# Set Date and Time in VBScript for Date object without changing system Date/Time

Tags: datetime, vbscript

I got the problem in VBScript when the Date (including Now) always calls from Windows system Date/Time.

How can I set the Date/Time for VBScipt without configuring system Date/Time in Windows.

e.g.

When call Date in VBS, Date will return the current system date(if today date is 1/1/2001)

```
Dim settingDate
settingDate = Date
//settingDate = 1/1/2001
```

I would like something to hooking up the VBS code to get Date from we set without changing Windows System Date/Time from code

```
//Implement something to tell VBS that current date is 12/12/2000
Dim settingDate
settingDate = Date
//settingDate = 12/12/2000
```

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? The system date should be the date, if you want something other than the date you can say `Mydate=#12/12/2000#` and use that.

Comment: Hi Remou, I'm developing the automated test tool to caheck the output value from many setting date and I would like to change all date in my code (which is using a lot) to other date. I do not want to change code because it's belonged to many developer. They are using the Date to get current date and I need to change it to other for testing.

Comment: How about Rob van der Woude http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetimenonbatch.php#SetDateVBS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just redefine Date(), Time(), Now(). POC script:

```
  WScript.Echo "Date()", Date()
  WScript.Echo "Time()", Time()
  WScript.Echo "Now()" , Now()
  ExecuteGlobal Join( Array( _
      "Function Date()" _
    , "  Date = #1/1/2012#" _
    , "End Function" _
    , "Function Time()" _
    , "  Time = TimeSerial( 1, 2, 3 )" _
    , "End Function" _
    , "Function Now()" _
    , "  Now = CDate( 4711.1147 )" _
    , "End Function" _
  ), vbCrLf )
  WScript.Echo "Date()", Date()
  WScript.Echo "Time()", Time()
  WScript.Echo "Now()" , Now()
```

output:

```
Date() 26.08.2011
Time() 14:19:41
Now() 26.08.2011 14:19:41
Date() 01.01.2012
Time() 01:02:03
Now() 23.11.1912 02:45:10
```